# How to get x,y position of contours in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get x and y positions of contours from the following image, but I messed up.
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctBI9.png)

I just need to find x and y positions of contours or center of the contours.

The results will be something like the following as I manually look up their positions from GIMP.

290, 210
982, 190
570, 478

I believe it can be done with cv2.findContours method, but I'm really out of ideas right now.

-Offtopic-

I will use these values in setting cursor position usingwin32api.SetCursorPos((xposition,yposition))

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer here

[Find Co-ordinates of Contours using OpenCV | Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-co-ordinates-of-contours-using-opencv-python/)

```
# Python code to find the co-ordinates of 
# the contours detected in an image. 
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

# Reading image 
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 
img2 = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

# Reading same image in another 
# variable and converting to gray scale. 
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Converting image to a binary image 
# ( black and white only image). 
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

# Going through every contours found in the image. 
for cnt in contours : 

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 

    # draws boundary of contours. 
    cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5) 

    # Used to flatted the array containing 
    # the co-ordinates of the vertices. 
    n = approx.ravel() 
    i = 0

    for j in n : 
        if(i % 2 == 0): 
            x = n[i] 
            y = n[i + 1] 

            # String containing the co-ordinates. 
            string = str(x) + " " + str(y) 

            if(i == 0): 
                # text on topmost co-ordinate. 
                cv2.putText(img2, "Arrow tip", (x, y), 
                                font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0)) 
            else: 
                # text on remaining co-ordinates. 
                cv2.putText(img2, string, (x, y), 
                        font, 0.5, (0, 255, 0)) 
        i = i + 1

# Showing the final image. 
cv2.imshow('image2', img2) 

# Exiting the window if 'q' is pressed on the keyboard. 
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Input image]

[image: Output image]

Comment: It is best to include the relevant bits of that link in your post. If the external link gets modified or removed in the future, your answer would still be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I have updated the answer. @eldesgraciado

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can do that with `findContours`. Since you have your contours there are several options:

1. Calculate enclosing rectangle and take e.g. the center point.
2. Calculate moments and take the centroid
3. Fit minimum enclosing circle and take the center
4. and so on...

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) are some examples of what you can do with your contours, including the options above.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find contours, draw a bounding box and then take the x and y from there. I hope this helps

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('ctBI9.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) <= 50 :
            continue    
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255,0), 2)
        center = (x,y)
        print (center)

while True: 
    cv2.imshow('test',im)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result is something like this
(93, 746)
(1174, 738)
(147, 736)
(395, 729)
(506, 404)
(240, 168)
(918, 130)