# How can I accurately extract dimensions and coordinates of rectangles using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, data-augmentation

I am currently trying to get the right dimensions/coordinates of some rectangles (check picture below) . I have so far tried two methods ;

the first being through contours where I get the contours of my rectangles and extract the (x,y) and width , height coordinates using cv2.boundingRect() function, however this yields to be fruitless as when I try to draw the same rectangles again with cv2.rectangle() function the rectangles are not the same, so I concluded that the function doesn't give me the right numbers or I might be using it the wrong way perhaps ?

```
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

coordinates = []

for cnt in contours : 

  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  coordinates.append([x,y,w,h])
```

The second method is one I found on [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441935/how-to-get-x-y-position-of-contours-in-python-opencv)]
This gives me the coordinates of the 4 corners of each rect , however I don't know how to use these coordinates to get the width and height of my rects.

To give you a bit of context, I have many images of black rectangles and I wish to separate/ =divide some of them into two rects and to do that I thought I'd get the coordinates of a random rect then draw a white rect over the black one with the same width ( or height if division is vertical ) the rect's height is gonna be smaller of course (or width if vertical ).

I am so puzzled, I spent 2 days now trying to figure out how to do this any help would be much appreciated !!
(I have also tried every post approaching this problem , but nothing was satisfying )

[image]

Edit :
Hello, I think I might have solved the issue yesterday, it still doesn't give me the "ideal" results I am looking for but it's working better.

Here is the full script of what I have done so far :

```
def split_vertical(img):
i = 1
# Reading image 
image = cv2.imread(img)
img2 = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Converting image to a binary image 
# ( black and white only image). 
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img2, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

coordinates = []

for cnt in contours : 

    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    coordinates.append([x,y,w,h])

# list of 6 random numbers (to put as index = 6 random rectanles)
numbers = [random.randint(0,len(coordinates)-1) for i in range(0,6)]

for j in numbers:
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
    
    new_image = image.copy()
    # Randomly select a rectangle for splitting
    x,y, width , height = coordinates[j]
    # height of the white rect aka splitting area 
    w =  int(random.uniform(0.03, 0.7) * width )
    split_position = int(x + (width/3))

    # Draw white rectangle 
    cv2.rectangle(new_image , (split_position,y) , (split_position+w  , y+height), (255,255,255) , -1)

    # Save image 
    cv2.imwrite(f"data_augmentation/split_vertical{timestamp}.png" , new_image)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Use cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats

Comment: First, use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`, then compare the binarized image to the original to verify that your threshold value is correct. Finally, follow @AlexAlex's suggestion.

Comment: Show your code for drawing the rectangles from x,y,w,h values.  You are probably making a mistake. (Show your full script)

Comment: @fmw42 I think that was exactly where I went wrong the first time. I have only just realized later on after posting this post that  I should use in the (width, height) arguments (x+width , y+ width) , after changing this + the random.uniform range it worked ! But nonetheless please have a look at my code, I could really use another pair of eyes to help improve the results